# Registering the SensorManager using SensorEventListener throws ClassCastException when running the application

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to develop a motion sensing application.

For this, I have created two Activities.
The first Activity takes the latitude and longitude from the user and there is a Button which saves the data and passes it onto the next Activity.
The second Activity is a GoogleMaps Activity, where I am using the user's data and all the respective managers (SensorManager, accelerometer, etc).

The first page is working fine, but when I enter the data and press the button,the application stops.
In the log, it shows that a ClassCastException is thrown in the MapsActivity class.

Please help.

Error:

```
12-21 17:14:44.564 5417-5417/com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall, PID: 5417
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall/com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall.MapsActivity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall.MapsActivity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener
      at com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:49)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall;

import android.app.usage.UsageEvents;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    float x,  y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText latitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitude1);
        final EditText longitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longitude1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                x= Float.parseFloat(latitude.getText().toString());
                y= Float.parseFloat(longitude.getText().toString());

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class);
                Bundle extras= new Bundle();
                extras.putFloat("LATITUDE",x);
                extras.putFloat("LONGITUDE",y);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });


    }


    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }




}
```

MapsActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Date;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    long lastUpdate=0;
    private float last_x,last_y;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        last_x = extras.getFloat("LATITUDE");
        last_y = extras.getFloat("LONGITUDE");
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // set up acclerometer
        sensorManager= (SensorManager)this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer= sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

**the below line is where the error is getting pointed to**

sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this,accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
        Sensor mySensor= event.sensor;

        if (mySensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
            float x= event.values[0];
            float y= event.values[1];

            long curTime= System.currentTimeMillis();

            if(Math.abs(curTime - lastUpdate)>2000){
                java.text.SimpleDateFormat date= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String currentDateTime= date.format(new Date());

                lastUpdate=curTime;

                if(Math.abs(last_x - x)>10)
                {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(last_x,last_y))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
                            .title("Hey you moved the x-axis on "+currentDateTime));

                }

                if(Math.abs(last_y - y)>10)
                {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(last_x,last_y))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                            .title("Hey you moved the y-axis on "+currentDateTime));

                }


                last_x=x;
                last_y=y;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy)
    {

    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(last_x,last_y);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Virginia Tech"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,14.9f));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:text="@string/Text_Name"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/latitude1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/latitude1"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/longitude1"
        android:hint="Enter the longitude"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/latitude1"
        android:hint="Enter the Latitude"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center" />

    <Button
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/longitude1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:onClick="sendData"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall.MapsActivity" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anurag.anurag_latest_morgenall">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have already entered all the necessary API key in the required places.

Comment: When it says `MapsActivity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener`, what do you think that means?

Comment: You should **implement SensorEventListener** with your **MapsActivity** then it becomes a sensor listener Activity and you will get sensor values in its overrided methods like onSensorChanged and onAccuracyChanged

Comment: thanks man for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

Hint: These methods do nothing

- `public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)`
- `public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy)`

Tip: Add `@Override` onto them to let the compiler warn you that you didn't implement the interface.

`class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {`